# test antd <Select/> using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, antd

How to change option properly using react testing library or enyzme ?

```
    function toggleOpen(wrapper) {
        act(() => {
            wrapper.find('.ant-select-selector').simulate('mousedown');
        });
    
        act(() => {
            wrapper.update();
        });
    }

export function selectItem(wrapper, index = 0) {
    act(() => {
        wrapper.find('.ant-select-item-option').simulate('click');
    });
}

describe('Select ', () => {
    it('should be able to select an option', async () => {
        
        let wrapper;
        act(() => {
            wrapper = mount(
                <Formik initialValues={{ paymentType: 5 }} onSubmit={jest.fn()}>
                    <Select name="paymentType">
                    <Select.Option value="5">abc</Select.Option>
                    <Select.Option value="6">xyz</Select.Option>
                </Select>

                </Formik>
            );
        });

        toggleOpen(wrapper);
        selectItem(wrapper)
        
    });
});
```

using above unable to select an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to test an antd `Select` component:

### Working Demo

Click [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/antd-select-testing) for a standalone demo

### Example Code

**App.js**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Select } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("lucy");

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Select
        defaultValue={value}
        style={{ width: 120 }}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
        <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
        <Option value="disabled" disabled>
          Disabled
        </Option>
        <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### Test Setup

DevDependencies:

- [@noshot/utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@noshot/utils)
- [@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17)
- [enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme)
- [jest-enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-enzyme#assertions)
- [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom)

**setupTests.js**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";
import "jest-enzyme";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/* THE BELOW ARE ACCESSIBLE AND PREDEFINED FOR ALL *.TEST.JS FILES */
const { document } = new JSDOM(
  "<!DOCTYPE html><body><div id='root'></div></body>"
).window;
global.document = document;
global.window = document.defaultView;
global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
global.HTMLAnchorElement = window.HTMLAnchorElement;
global.React = React;
global.requestAnimationFrame = (callback) => setTimeout(callback, 0);
global.cancelAnimationFrame = (id) => clearTimeout(id);

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: "node.js",
};
```

### Tests

**App.test.js** (you can read more about waitForAct [here](https://github.com/no-shot/utils#waitforact))

```js
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { waitForAct } from "@noshot/utils";
import App from "./App";

const wrapper = mount(<App />);

describe("App", () => {
  it("updates the select input value when an option is clicked", async () => {
    // expect initial value to be "Lucy"
    expect(wrapper.find(".ant-select-selection-item")).toHaveText("Lucy");

    // click on select input to open dropdown
    wrapper.find(".ant-select-selector").simulate("mousedown");

    // wait for the dropdown to appear and expect that it has 4 options
    await waitForAct(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      expect(wrapper.find(".ant-select-item")).toHaveLength(4);
    });

    // select the first option ("Jack")
    wrapper.find(".ant-select-item").first().simulate("click");

    // wait for the select input to update with the selected option ("Jack")
    await waitForAct(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      expect(wrapper.find(".ant-select-selection-item")).toHaveText("Jack");
    });
  });
});
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: let wrapper;
  act(() => {
   wrapper = mount(<Home />, {
    wrappingComponent: Provider,
    wrappingComponentProps: {store: store}
   });
  })
  screen.debug(document)

Comment: in above my comment only output style sheet. not the document html. any reason ?

Comment: You seem to be mixing `@testing-library` with `enzyme`. Please fork my github repo and add the code you're trying to test. If you still run into issues, share your source (via github link).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68173228/jest-doesnt-find-the-conditional-rendering-element can you check this too?

Comment: The problem now is when we set the Formik state and the conditional rendering attach to it doesn't seems to get updated.

Comment: Could you able to find any issue with above ?

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that worked for me :

```
describe('antd dropdown test', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Comoponent />);
  });

  it('test the serachable dropdown', async () => {
    const dropdownInput = await wrapper.find('input.ant-select-selection-search-input').first();
    await dropdownInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'new test agro' } });
    const dropdown = await wrapper.find('.ant-select-selector');
    await dropdown.first().simulate('mousedown');
    await waitFor(() => {
      wrapper.update();
    });
    await wrapper.find('.ant-select-item').first().simulate('click'); // to click on first option in dropdown
  });
});
```

hope that this works for you.